# Trying to grab a string with one substring static, and one dynamic

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to find the best way to grab the dynamic substring, but replace all of the content after.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

`{table_telecommunications}`

The substring `{table_` is always the same, the only that varies is `telecommunications}`.

I want to grab the word telecommunications so I can do a search on a MySQL table and then replace `{table_telecommunications}` with the content returned.

I thought of making a `strpos` and then `explode` and so on.

But I guess it would be easier with regex, but I have no skills on creating regex.

Could you possibly give me the best way to do this?

**Edit:** I'm saying possibly regex is the best way because I need to find strings that are in this format, but the second part is variable, just like `{table_*}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex.

```
<?php
    $string = "{table_telecommunications} blabla blabla {table_block}";
    preg_match_all("/\{table_(.+?)\}/is", $string, $matches);
    $substrings = $matches[1];

    print_r($substrings);
?>
```

Comment: If my string is `{table_telecommunications} blabla blabla {table_block}`, the array match will only contain `['{table_telecommunications}', 'telecommunications']`...

Comment: Great and simple solution, Regex is always usefull.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match('#table_([^}]+)}#', '{table_telecommunications}', $matches)){
    echo $matches[1];
}
```

That's a regex solution. You can do the same with explode:

```
$parts = explode('table_', '{table_telecommunications}');
echo substr($parts[1], 0, -1);
```

Comment: I only want to grab the ones that begin with `{table_`, can you edit your answer so that it suits my needs?

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = '{table_telecommunications}';
$table_name = trim(implode('_', array_shift(explode($input, '_'))), '}');
```

Should be fast, no regex required.